# exhibit a countable set of irrational numbers with justification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers

So I have been given this problem and I am totally stumped on what to do...everything I have learned says the irrational numbers are uncountable but I am supposed to exhibit a countable set of irrational numbers. This implies that there is a bijection from this countable set (lets call it S) to the natural numbers or a bijection from the natural numbers to this countable set S.

- any thoughts on what I should I do would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Take $\{n+\pi \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. The bijection is obvious and each element here is irrational.

Comment: appreciate it H.Potter !

Comment: Another example: $\{\pi + x \mid x\in\mathbb Q\}$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{\sqrt p \mid p$ is prime$\}$.

Comment: thx ahmed sadly we havent gotten to prime numbers in class and we are strictly forbidden from using concepts not discussed in class so I will be using H.Potters idea

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternate.
The definition I know of countable says that a set has to be finite or denumerable.

The set $\{\pi\}$ is countable. In fact, it is finite.

Comment: This is a possible solution. Although, many authors use the term countable to mean "in bijection with $\Bbb N$".

Comment: Yes, I am aware. Thank you. I just posted in the case this was meant to be a trick/easy question, if the author also includes "finite" as countable.